# Focus to bottom cell when keyboard up and there is one row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have simple chat layout contains tableview and textfield in the bottom in ViewController. im using following method when keyboard appears(move view up). everything works fine excepts when there is a single item(chat message) in the tableView.

Problem is when there is only one row and when keyboard up row will not be visible to the user. when there is multiple rows(chats) this is not a problem. in that case user wont see the last message while he types the next message.  i thought of reducing tableview height when keyboard up it didnt work for me correctly. i may have used wrong approache. can anyone suggest me good solution for this. i have attached screenshot a

```
 func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Use IQKeyboardManager library is best for handling all keyboard event automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing view bottom constraints constant.so im not moving up view like above.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            self.bottomConstantTableView.constant += keyboardSize.height
            self.tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: false)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            self.bottomConstantTableView.constant -= keyboardSize.height
            self.tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: false)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TPKeyboardAvoiding**

TPKeyboardAvoiding library is handling all keyboard event in UICollectionView, UITableView, UIScrollView

use this library in your project your problem will be solved.

Here is [link](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

**Usage**

Just give a TPKeyboardAvoiding class based on UIViewController (no extra coding required )

[image]

Thank you